# How is memory allocated for empty list, tuple, dictionary?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am new to python programming, as per OOps Concepts memory will allocated for every Object,
in python programming, how the memory is allocated for `[ ]`, `{ }`, `( )` objects without elements?

Thanks
Mukthayr

Comment: why do you need to know? In general you don't need to worry about memory allocation in python

Comment: The short answer is "exactly the same as for containers *with* elements."

Answer (score 4):

If you're worrying about memory allocation for empty elements in Python, you're doing it wrong.

Python is a high-level language with automatic memory management. Unless you're trying to deal with huge amounts of data in a severely memory-restricted environment, you should not be thinking about this.

Comment: Hi,while i use sys module getsizeof found this results                  sys.getsizeof({})
136
sys.getsizeof([])
32
sys.getsizeof(())
24 because of this results i worried about memory.

Comment: @user1308308 If you're that memory constrained, you're not looking for python, but [c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). There the answer is "How much you tell it to allocate"

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers say you don't need to know and you shouldn't care. In general empty lists and dictionaries are just like any other list or dictionary: indeed since you can mutate an empty list/dictionary it may later become non-empty.

However, the empty tuple is slightly different as in at least some implementations of Python it is a singleton value. It is exceedingly unlikely that this will ever matter to you, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on python interpreter implementation. And, actually, you can do nothing with that except for tuning garbage collection (see [gc module](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html)). Don't care, your interpreter do.